# How to override Django's default response code?

Tags: python, django, http-status-codes

I have two classes in my `views.py` to handle `GET` all users, `GET` one user and `POST` a new user. If I try to post a user with an `id` that already exists, Django throws the default 400 - bad request -error. What I'd like to do is send a 409 conflict error instead. How could I achieve this?

I tried and succeeded to get the request when posting new object, but I don't know how to get the response.

These are my classes:

```
class UserListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = User.objects.all()

    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]



class UserView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny)

    queryset = User.objects.all()

    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Comment: How do you  specify the ID when you create an user ? In the URL or in the data you send to the view ?

Comment: @May.D The user ID comes predefined, I can't change that. I'm setting the ID like this in my model: `id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, blank=False, max_length=100)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried to reproduce your problem but it is quite unclear to me what you are trying to accomplish. When doing a `POST` request you should not specify the ID, because `POST` is used to create a new element and the ID is automatically created by the backend. [This website](https://restfulapi.net/rest-put-vs-post/) explains how POST request should be used.

Anyway, if you want to override the response code, you need to override your view `post` method like below.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
    except Exception:  # you must find the exact Exception raised here
        return Response(status=409)
```